# how to make the Curve shape and join it with the another mesh

Tags: modeling

I am new to the blender and aiming to make the below model for practice which i picked from google images. But i am having difficulty in making the curve part.

[image]

I tried making the curve using another cylinder mesh and solidfy modifier and then used boolean modifier to make the curved hole but how do i make that extruded curve and add it to the mesh.

In the below image i made the curve hole using semi cylinder and boolean modifier. But i dont know how to do the extruded curve and the slant shape.

[image]

And in the next image i tried to make the extruded curve but i dont know how to add it to the rest of the mesh. Do I need to make loop cuts in the square below and fill each face or is there any other method.

[image]

sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Booleans are rarely the recommended answer. Can you show us what you got?

Comment: are you trying to do the whole object in one piece?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  I have updated my question. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the semi-spherical shape alone, you can do it this way. If you want to make the whole object in one piece you will have to apply the *Solidify* modifier and start with this topology, which is totally possible.

[image]